# Finding all CICS regions containing a program through Ansible

Tags: ansible, cics

I'm using the [IBM z/OS CICS collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ibm/ibm_zos_cics) for Ansible. I need to be able to find all CICS regions that contain a particular program, and automate that on a regular basis.

I have CMCI set up and have tested that. I can also get all programs like this:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: 'Get all programs'
      delegate_to: 'localhost'
      ibm.ibm_zos_cics.cmci_get:
        type: 'CICSProgram'
        scope: [redacted]
```

I'm not quite sure how I should filter the programs or how I should map the result into the CICS region name, and return it as a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a playbook something like this, which uses [filter](https://ibm.github.io/z_ansible_collections_doc/ibm_zos_cics/docs/source/modules/cmci_get.html#:%7E:text=filter,-A%20dictionary%20with%20attribute%20names%20as%20keys) to find all instances of a `PROGRAM` resource with a specific name.

It then uses the built-in `debug` module combined with a Jinja filter to extract the name of the region each `PROGRAM` was found in, finally joining them into a comma-separated list:

```yaml
---
- name:  CICS CMCI Report

  collections:
      - ibm.ibm_zos_cics

  hosts: 'localhost'
  gather_facts: 'false'

  vars:
    program_name: MYPROG
    context: CICSPLEX
    cmci_host: 'example.com'
    cmci_port: 12345

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure CMCI module dependencies are installed
      pip:
        name:
          - requests
          - xmltodict

    - name: Find all instances of a particular program
      cmci_get:
        context: '{{ context }}'
        cmci_host: '{{ cmci_host }}'
        cmci_port: '{{ cmci_port }}'
        type: 'CICSProgram'
        resources:
          filter:
            program: '{{ program_name }}'
      register: result

    - name: Extract the CICS region names from the program records
      debug:
        msg: "{{ result.records | map(attribute='eyu_cicsname') | join(',') }}"
```